# Cannot align text with a line drawn on an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to do some image manipulation with the python library Pillow (fork of PIL) and am coming across a weird problem. For some reason, when I try to draw a line and draw some text at the same y coordinate, they're not matching up. The text is a bit below the line, yet I have both graphics starting at the same point. Has anyone had this problem before and/or know how to solve it? Here's the code I'm using:

```
image = Image.open("../path_to_image/image.jpg")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

font = ImageFont.truetype("../fonts/Arial Bold.ttf", 180)

draw.line((0,2400, 500,2400), fill="#FFF", width=1)
draw.text((0, 2400), "Test Text", font=font) 

image.save(os.path.join(root, "test1.jpg"), "JPEG", quality=100)

return
```

Comment: I manually created a photo with photoshop that had a line at 2400 on the y axis, and the draw.line correctly drew the line over the image, so it appears that for some reason the `draw.text` method has some issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get something similar (with sizes 10 times smaller):

[image: example test1.jpg output]

This is happening because the (x,y) coordinates given to [ImageDraw.text()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text) are the **top** left corner of the text:

> PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text(xy, text, fill=None, font=None, anchor=None)
>
> Draws the string at the given position.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - xy – Top left corner of the text.
> - text – Text to be drawn.
> - font – An ImageFont instance.
> - fill – Color to use for the text.

This is confirmed in the [code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/ImageDraw.py#L255-L273): the text is turned into a bitmap and then drawn at xy.

Comment: Right, if the x,y coords are the top left of the text, I would expect the line drawn to be across the very top of the text, which is not happening. The line and the text have a fair amount of space between them. It seems that you're having that problem too...? Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: My guess is this is what's labelled 'top bearing line' here: http://www.myfirstfont.com/images/glyphterms.gif and described as 'top side bearing' here: http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html

Answer (score 0):

For those with a similar problem, I ended up creating a helper function that manually adjusts the font size until `font.getsize(text)[1]` returns the correctly sized text. Here's a snippet:

```
def adjust_font_size_to_line_height(font_location, desired_point_size, text):
    adjusted_points = 1

    while True:
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_location, adjusted_points)
        height = font.getsize(text)[1]

        if height != desired_point_size:
            adjusted_points += 1
        else:
            break

    return adjusted_points
```